# Unknown complication type on default Galaxy Watch 4 face

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-complication

I am trying to investigate and duplicate some complication types I see on Samsung's Galaxy Watch 4. Namely, this complication (3) on the Info Brick watch face: [Screenshot of Wear app on S21](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MSmQ.png)

Can anyone tell me what complication type this is?

I've been reading documentation on complications in WearOS. [There are various non-text types](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/watch-faces/adding-complications#types-fields): `SMALL_IMAGE`, `LARGE_IMAGE`, `ICON`.

I wrote a data source "app" and supplied those 3 ComplicationTypes, but none of them show up as options when I try to customize the watch face.

Comment: What makes you think that UI is using the complication APIs? It is their watchface and their configuration activity can change any setting, not just things related to the complication APIs.

Comment: When I attempt to customize the watch face, I'm given more options to select data providers from other Samsung apps. Can you have custom data types in watch faces or data providers?

Comment: If they are using the Complications API my guess would be that they are of type RANGED_VALUE. This would allow them to be rendered with both a value and a progress towards some sort of goal (as seen with both the bars and pie chart).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pulling the comment by @ianhanniballake up to an answer.

Watchfaces developers can make watchfaces with additional data displayed like complications. Particularly for a device manufacturer (OEM) like Samsung, who can safely and securely access additional health data.

These can have different shape, or animations or real time data if the OEM decides to implement them that way.

There are requirements to support the standard complications for OEMs.

But it does mean you can't replicate all complications you see on Samsung watchfaces.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this makes sense.

I can't see that documentation, I get a 404. Do I need a special sign in to view it?

Comment: You would, I guess it's only shared with OEM partners.  Removed it.

Comment: This answer was a bit convoluted for me... This means Samsung made some custom complication types which only them and other accredited OEMs could add to watchfaces? This doesn't seem to be a matter of "custom data displaying like a complication", but it's a specific complication which allows many data sources (as any editable complication does).